# preg_match_all to include all results plus ones without a certain value

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to do a preg_match_all on the following string:

```
    $string1 = '/<a href="(.*?).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico)"><img(.*?)class="(.*?)wp-image-(.*?)" title="(.*?)" (.*?) \/><\/a>/i';
preg_match_all( $string, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The above works fine for what i'm doing, the problem is I also need to detect images without the "title" tag.

Is there a way to do a preg_match_all and also add matches if the string doesn't have value[6]? (title flag is value[6]), and give those results (without title) a special name (i.e $matches_no_title?

My current solution is to run two preg_match_all on two different strings (same string except one doesn't have the title="" part), but if I could do it all in one preg_match_all to optimize the website speed, that would be better!

Comment: not exactly but  (title="(.*?)" (.*?) )?

Comment: I wanted to isolate the title info, without the second (.*?) the title flag value becomes whatever is inside the title + everything that follows. Is that not a good way to separate flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the `title` attribute comes (right) after the `class` attribute, it's simple. Just make it optional.

```
$string1 = '/<a href="(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico)"><img(.*?)class="(.*?)wp-image-(.*?)"(?: title="(.*?)")? (.*?) \/><\/a>/i';
```

Do note that the regex is to specific to match general HTML.

In this case you might be better of using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) with [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) or a library like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

regex it is not the best approach on what do you want. You can try parsing the HTML and get what do you want.

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think alternation with a null will do what you want:

```
$string1 = '/<a href="(.*?).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico)"><img(.*?)class="(.*?)wp-image-(.*?)" (|title="(.*?)") (.*?) \/><\/a>/i';
preg_match_all( $string1, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

You may also need to get fancy about optional whitespace; as it is, you'll be expecting to match a space before and after the optional title="blah" tokens, which means that the match would look for two spaces if the title="blah" isn't there... so you may want

```
wp-image-(.*?)"(| title="(.*?)" )(.*?) \/>
```

or

```
wp-image-(.*?)"(|\s+title="(.*?)"\s+)(.*?) \/>
```

instead of

```
wp-image-(.*?)" (|title="(.*?)") (.*?) \/>
```